# Bash CSV get a column?

Tags: bash, csv

```
 row1    row2         row3
Hello,   World,    Hello World
World,   Hello,    World Hello
```

How do you grab the entire 2 words in bash? I have tried and all I could do is using `echo $a tr -s ' ' | cut -d , -f 3` to get both words but each word will be put on its own line like:-

```
Hello
World
World
Hello
```

Comment: Is this is a `.csv` file, why are you using `echo $a`? Provide a clear verifiable input and an expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` with custom field separator as space or comma:

```
awk -F '[ ,]+' 'NR>1{print $1, $2}' file

Hello World
World Hello
```